# How to increase the speed of mouse keys?

Tags: mouse-keys

I mean the keys on my numpad used to control the mouse pointer when there isn't a mouse. It moves really slow, like 10 pixels per second or something in those lines. And xkbset doesn’t work since ubuntu 22.04 uses wayland not xorg.

Comment: Please [edit] your question and give us some context. What Ubuntu are you using? What are mouse keys, do you mean mouse buttons? Or do you have some sort of special mouse? Do you mean you are using the keyboard keys to move the mouse around? What does "speed" mean here? The speed of a double click? Mouse movement? Something else? How does `xkbset` fail? What did you try and what happened?

Answer (score 0):

Solved the problem by installing dconf-editor and searching the "mousekeys"(without the double quotation marks) phrase and increased the speed.